# Chrome radial css gradient smoothness

Tags: google-chrome, css, safari

Im using `chrome 18.0.1025.162` and am trying to do a radial gradient

```
-webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9))
```

The problem is that the gradient is very pixelated sort of, the transition in color and alpha is in blocks and not smooth. This is different in Safari and Firefox. Safari & Firefox do it very smoothly and well

Is this a bug with chrome? Anyone have the same problem with this. Its such a simple gradient!! Surely something as simple as this can't be a glitch

Check out : http://jsfiddle.net/GyRLe/1/ for a demo of what I mean.

Is there a solution for this? An image would be awful :(

(Ok so to see how bad the smoothness is):
This is what I get when im using it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfRWk.png (Chrome)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrLCr.png (Safari)  (Seems a bit edgy but thats because of the png, otherwise its close to perfect smoothness)

Firefox is just as good as Safari its just chrome is doing it badly 
I need alpha because Im putting an repeat style image in the background

Edit: Chrome 20 (Canary) also had this horrid issue!

Edit2: The reason we use CSS is so we dont have to use images! So I've added this to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123491 & hopefully google gets their act straight because I think chrome is wonderful

Comment: Nope! There's no solution. You'll have to use an image.

Comment: It looks very smooth to me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sal39.png (Chrome 18.0.1025.142 (Ubuntu 11.10)).

Comment: Compare with safari (my example isn't very good but with one of my configurations (with an image as the background) it comes horrible)

Comment: Thats not smooth btw (compare this) http://i.imgur.com/3SYXW.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that it have been posted quite a long time ago, but I encountered the same issue (strong banding) with Chrome 24 using :

```
-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #XXXXXX 0%,#YYYYYY 100%);
```

But I realized that using the code below the banding almost disappeared :

```
-webkit-gradient(radial, center, 0px, center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#XXXXXX), color-stop(100%,#YYYYYY));
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** I've seen that -webkit-gradient(radial, ...) is just the old syntax for radial gradient display, so it should not be a long term answer for that issue...

Comment: Welp. This answer is no longer suitable. :(

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the alpha value, it looks a lot smoother using `rgb` instead of `rgba`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tKtV9/

Comment: There's absolutely no change when transparency is added. Try decreasing the color range - e.g. white to gray gradient and you'll see the bands

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't help much in this case, but I have noticed that adding

```
width: x-value;
height: y-value;
```

sometimes can help. X-value and Y-value, of course, being your dimensions.

Comment: Where did you add it? I already use height and width (like in the jsfiddle - I just threw it in the div instead of the css)

Comment: Yes, like you did. But when adding the gradient to html or body, for example, I have noticed setting a width/height helps smooth the gradient.