# Pixelated rendering of radial gradient in Chrome on Windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, css, radial-gradients

For reference, see this question: **[Chrome radial css gradient smoothness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157495/chrome-radial-css-gradient-smoothness).**

The OP is having trouble with the smoothness of the gradient, but from the discussion it seems that that's only when using alpha transparency.

---

Here's the gradient I'm using:

```css
div {
    background: radial-gradient(
        #000 30%,
        transparent 30%, transparent 40%,
        #000 40%, #000 60%,
        transparent 60%
    );
}
```

As you can see, it's using hard stops (so no color transition) and no `rgba` (so no alpha either). Still, in Chrome (tested in 23 on Windows 7) it's rendered extremely pixelated:

[image]

Is this just the way Chrome handles these things, or am I missing something? Is there anything that can be done to smoothen it out a bit (short of using an image, obviously)?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wARGc/

---

**Update:** [I filed a bug report for this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162048).

Comment: weird , just messing with it I got it to look smooth , but really changed what it looked like - so I'm not going to post

Comment: @ScottSelby - I think you should post. Seeing what you did different might just give us a clue as to what might be causing this.

Comment: The same is for circle - div with border-radius 50% of it's width/height with transparent mask applied.

Comment: Three years and 32 versions later, this is still an issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a rendering problem by Chrome, you can create the smoothing yourself by adjusting the shape slightly. See my update to your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jamestoone/XU7jB/

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: radial-gradient(#000 30%, transparent 30%, transparent 40%, #000 40%, #000 60%, transparent 60%);
}

div.new {
    background: radial-gradient(#000000 30%, transparent 32%, transparent 38%, #000000 40%, #000000 60%, transparent 62%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I accepted this answer since it solves my problem somewhat, but this is still very weird. [I filed a bug for it](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162048). Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

When building a reusable code that will take different sizes, playing with percentages is not an option because it can fit only a single size of the gradient container, and will distort a smaller or larger one.

Yet, I found that setting explicitly a distance of 1px for the gradient to be smooth between each gradient step, solves completely the problem.

So for each step, instead of setting twice the same percentage, like 40%, just give one of them a pixel more space: `calc(40% - 1px)`.

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/zgmfe9v2/

[Smooth radial gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipAlb.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's a Chrome issue of rendering a crisp boundary. First we need to understand the ripple effect here. If we have `#000` ending at `30%`, the starting `transparent` with `30%` will create a crisp/pixelated boundary. So in order to smooth it, we provide `#000` with `29.8%`, which resolves the issue.

**Old CSS:**

```css
background: radial-gradient(
  circle at center,
  #494646 10%,
  #494646 31%,
  #221f1f 31%,
  #221f1f 41%,
  #494646 41%,
);
```

**Resolved:**

```css
background: radial-gradient(
  circle at center,
  #494646 10%,
  #494646 30.8%,
  #221f1f 31%,
  #221f1f 40.8%,
  #494646 41%,
);
```