# CSS radial gradient not applying from center

Tags: css, google-chrome

So I have some code:

```
body
{
    /*background:#52895F;*/

    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #52895F 40%, #CDCDCD);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, #52895F 40%, #CDCDCD);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #52895F 40%, #CDCDCD);
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #52895F 40%, #CDCDCD);
}
```

Everything is fine except for the middle colour (#52895F) appearing a little bit to the right from the center on Google Chrome. Not a big deal (can't see it normally), but when I try to put some logo/text in the center, I can clearly see the gradient not being applied well. On Safari everything is fine. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Take a look at this article addressing same issue; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157495/chrome-radial-css-gradient-smoothness Rgds,

Comment: Not the same issue actually. They talk about 'smoothness' of the gradient, but my problem is the gradient not starting in the center of the body.

Comment: You can try their solution and see if the same issue exists. If so, then problem is likely to be a persistent one. Otherwise, try to make use of their solution. Rgds

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
body{
    background: radial-gradient(circle at center center, #52895F 40%, #CDCDCD);
}
```